# Redis handling of Huge DataSet

Tags: database, redis

One of the (left) advantages of the classic relational DBs over Redis that I heard of is that in use case of storing a lot of large datasets (e.g. in size of 20 GB) it's better keep using DB such as MySQL.
My question according to the fact that Redis have got the sharding capability (meaning to split the value into pieces) - Is it still an issue that relational DBs are better than Redis?

(for example in terms of read/write efficiency, the complexity of making queries regarding those datasets, etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is strictly a matter of using the right tool for the job. Both an RDBMS and a NoSQL solution (such as Redis) can be used for storing big data sets - I have intimate acquaintance with Redis databases over 1TB for example.

The biggest "downside" of using Redis to store data is the cost - since Redis is (atm) an in-memory database, you'll be paying more (compared to a disk-based RDBMS). The gains, otoh, are speed, speed and speed :) If you can get away with using something like MySQL (or better yet, PostgreSQL) then by all means do that. If your requirements call for a more performant solution, consider using an RDBMS in conjunction with Redis (i.e. for caching or storing hot data). When all else fails and you need "webscale" - Redis is probably your best bet.